# i want to fectch date from data base and display in dd/mm/yy formate in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

**my code is in view**

```
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $projects_count = $projects_count + 1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p_key->title; ?></td>
    <td><?php $clients_list = $this->clients_model->getById($p_key->client_id); 
    extract($clients_list);
    echo $title; ?></td>

    <td><?php
    $getdate=$p_key->estimated_start_date;
    $pieces = explode("/", $getdate);
$comdate=$pieces[0].$pieces[1].$pieces[2];
echo $comdate;


    ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p_key->estimated_end_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p_key->actual_start_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p_key->actual_end_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p_key->status; ?></td>
```

it this estimated date section i want to dislplay in dd-mm-yy but it show error why

Comment: whats the output of $getdate; pls show us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($p_key->estimated_start_date));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with -

```
<td><?php echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($getdate));?></td>
```